# I'm Getting Count of a column same for all rows?How to count occurrences of a column value efficiently in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
Select 
       Sales_Detail.Serial_No
       ,Sales_Detail.Tax_Percentage
       ,Card_Amount
       ,Cash_Amount
       ,ISNULL((Select  Count(DISTINCT  Tax_Percentage) From Sales_Detail
        Left Join Sales_Master  ON 
        Sales_Master.Serial_No=Sales_Detail.Serial_No
        Where Sales_Master.Invoice_Date = '14-Feb-2019' 
       And IsSaved='True'And IsCancelled = 'False'
       And Card_Amount >0 Or Sales_Master.Cash_Amount>0 
       And Sales_Detail.Serial_No=10467),1) As Count_Tax    

From Sales_Detail    
Inner Join Item_Master On Sales_Detail.Item_ID = Item_Master.Item_ID
Inner Join Item_Brand On Item_Master.Brand_ID = Item_Brand.Brand_ID
Inner Join Sales_Master On Sales_Detail.Serial_No=Sales_Master.Serial_No
left Join Customer C on C.Customer_ID =Sales_Master.Customer_ID     
Inner Join Tax On Tax.Tax_Percentage=Sales_Detail.Tax_Percentage 

Where Sales_Master.Invoice_Date = '14-Feb-2019' And IsSaved = 'True' 
And IsCancelled = 'False'
order by Sales_Detail.SGST_Percentage ,Tax_Percentage
```

While taking count from above query.
I'm getting count as 2 for all row .Why is it so??
If above select in the query expected the output count as 2 for all rows ,
But actually I want to set count as 1 for serial No 10467 and count as 2 for serial No 10468.

```
Select
     Count(DISTINCT Tax_Percentage)
  From Sales_Detail

  Left Join Sales_Master ON Sales_Master.Serial_No=Sales_Detail.Serial_No

  Where Sales_Master.Invoice_Date = '14-Feb-2019'
  And IsSaved='True'And IsCancelled = 'False'
  And Card_Amount >0 Or Sales_Master.Cash_Amount>0
  And Sales_Detail.Serial_No=10467
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJJrs.png)

Comment: It's hard to understand what you expected.

Comment: But, even tough - your COUNT sub query is hardcoded to only one value of `serial_no`, so it's expected to always return the same result. If I got you right you should pass the parent query `serial_no` to the sub query.

Comment: It Not HardCoded,Orginal Query It is As Below:

ISNULL((Select  Count(DISTINCT  Tax_Percentage) From Sales_Detail
            Left Join Sales_Master  ON Sales_Master.Serial_No=Sales_Detail.Serial_No
            Where Sales_Master.Invoice_Date = @InvoiceDate And IsSaved = 'True' And IsCancelled = 'False'
           And Card_Amount >0 Or Sales_Master.Cash_Amount>0 And Sales_Detail.Serial_No=@SerialNo ),1)

Comment: Then Also its not woking.Why is it So??

Comment: when you assign value to the variable `@SerialNo`? Is it part of loop? where the values come from? if you start your procedure with `@SerialNo=10467`it is still hardcoding.

Comment: I re-read your question and so this line "...I Want to set Count as 1 For Serial No 10467 And Count As 2 For Serial No 10468" - do you mean you want to force it to be 1 for 10467 and 2 for 10468? if so you can accomplish it with simple condition.

Answer (score 0):

In your select you are hardcoding the Searial_No `And Sales_Detail.Serial_No=10467` so for each row you will get the same value.

Change  your like following.

```
Select 
       Sales_Detail.Serial_No
       ,Sales_Detail.Tax_Percentage
       ,Card_Amount
       ,Cash_Amount
       ,ISNULL((Select  Count(DISTINCT  Tax_Percentage) From Sales_Detail SD
        Left Join Sales_Master  ON 
        Sales_Master.Serial_No=SD.Serial_No
        Where Sales_Master.Invoice_Date = '14-Feb-2019' 
       And IsSaved='True'And IsCancelled = 'False'
       And Card_Amount >0 Or Sales_Master.Cash_Amount>0 
       And SD.Serial_No=Sales_Detail.Serial_No     
       ),1) As Count_Tax    

From Sales_Detail    
Inner Join Item_Master On Sales_Detail.Item_ID = Item_Master.Item_ID
Inner Join Item_Brand On Item_Master.Brand_ID = Item_Brand.Brand_ID
Inner Join Sales_Master On Sales_Detail.Serial_No=Sales_Master.Serial_No
left Join Customer C on C.Customer_ID =Sales_Master.Customer_ID     
Inner Join Tax On Tax.Tax_Percentage=Sales_Detail.Tax_Percentage 

Where Sales_Master.Invoice_Date = '14-Feb-2019' And IsSaved = 'True' 
And IsCancelled = 'False'
order by Sales_Detail.SGST_Percentage ,Tax_Percentage
```

**Suggestion** : As a good practice always use alias names for your table so that it can be easily used at multiple places without confusion.

Comment: .Thank you for the Answer.Serial No Used is Not  hardcoded.I Just want to display here for my question

Comment: I added the condition  And SD.Serial_No=Sales_Detail.Serial_No  did you tested afte that?